# Link with Cocoa Framework from C++ and Objective-C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocoa, linker

I'm trying to use a Cocoa Framework (MultitouchSupport, to be specific) from within a basic Objective-C++ file, but I keep getting undefined symbol errors, as if g++ is supposed to have different linker flags than gcc.

My ultimate goal is to integrate a C++ networking library with some basic Objective-C code I got from here: http://steike.com/code/multitouch/.

When I run this to compile the original code, it works fine:

```
gcc -F/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks -framework MultitouchSupport test.m -o test -std=c99
```

But when I rename the file to `test.mm`, so that it can later include and reference C++ files, the following doesn't work:

```
g++ -F/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks -framework MultitouchSupport test.mm -o test
```

And gives me these errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"MTDeviceCreateDefault()", referenced from:
    _main in ccq0vzuM.o
"MTRegisterContactFrameCallback(void*, int (*)(int, Finger*, int, double, int))", referenced from:
    _main in ccq0vzuM.o
"MTDeviceStart(void*, int)", referenced from:
    _main in ccq0vzuM.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [testpp] Error 1
```

What do I need to do in order for this Objective-C++ file to see the Framework I'm looking for so I can use C++ with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the header that declares those three functions, is there an `extern "C"` block that wraps them? Something like this?

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

// function declarations here

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

If not: You could add one to the header file, or add a similar wrapper around your `#import` of that header file.

Comment: Thank you so much! I assumed the whole `extern "C"` thing was only relevant for mixing C++ with C.

Everything compiles, now I just have to test it :)

Comment: Well, you *are* mixing C++ with C. You've got plain C functions in that library, and you're trying to access them from C++ (actually, Objective-C++) code. The fact that the library and/or your code may also have some Obj-C code in them doesn't make any difference.